# How can I get the number of confirmations for specific transaction hash?

Tags: web3js

everyone!
I have faced with one problem.
I can find the transaction hash once transaction is created.
Because I am watching the blocks with `newBlockHeader` event.
At the moment, I want to check and update the confirmation number of this transaction.
I tried with [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/how-does-current-block-number-block-number-of-a-given-transaction-gives-the)

`web3.eth.blockNumber-web3.eth.getTransaction(<txhash>).blockNumber`.

But it returns `NaN`. 
How can I do?

Comment: What do each of those commands return when run individually?

Comment: web3.eth.blockNumber: undefined

web3.eth.getTransaction(<txhash>).blockNumber : undefined

Both of 2 values are all `undefined`.
And `eth.syncing` returns `false` in geth console

Answer (score 1):

6 years....

So what about a solution? In v6 ethers.js we can do something like this:

```js
const tx = await this.eth.getTransactionReceipt(params.hash);

console.log('tx', tx);
console.log('tx confirmations', await tx.confirmations());
```

> tx ...
> tx confirmations 65