# How do I get the confirmations of a transaction programmaticallly?

Tags: solidity, transactions, confirmations

Can I get the confirmations of a transaction using Solidity? If not, is there any other method I can use to get confirmations programmatically?

I hope when user submits one transaction, the web can show the result and the result won't be changed later. The users accept to wait the longer time, example 1 or 3 minutes, for making sure the transaction is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Solidity and the web are different.  Solidity itself does not have access to past transactions.  For the web, you would use web3.js and see the code at [How can a DApp detect a fork or chain reorganization using web3.js or additional libraries?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-a-dapp-detect-a-fork-or-chain-reorganization-using-web3-js-or-additional) which waits specified number of blocks and verifies the transaction receipt is still valid.  In this method, the user doesn't have to wait 1 or 3 minutes (after they click a button to submit a transaction), and if there is a chain reorg, the UI can be updated: the UI could let the user know that they have to resubmit their transaction.

Comment: Sir,I read the link and have a more clear concept.Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

This was mentioned in another [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/how-to-get-the-transaction-confirmations-using-the-json-rpc?rq=1), also [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/43wj2p/how_do_i_get_the_number_of_confirmations_on_a/)

Number of confirmations is the current block number minus the transaction's block number (if any).

For web3, this can be found by the following command

```
web3.eth.blockNumber - web3.eth.getTransaction(<txhash>).blockNumber
```

I think the same would also work in Geth console after removing the `web3.`'s.