# Why computed number of confirmations is a lot larger than value from the block explorer?

Tags: web3.py, polygon, confirmations

As it has been explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12609/how-do-i-get-the-confirmations-of-a-transaction-programmaticallly), [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/how-to-get-the-transaction-confirmations-using-the-json-rpc?rq=1) and even [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/43wj2p/how_do_i_get_the_number_of_confirmations_on_a/) I proceed with computing number of confirmations for a given `txid`. It works but gives weird results which are not consistent with the block explorer.

Using

```py
receipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(txid)
result = _contract.events.Transfer().processReceipt(receipt, errors=DISCARD)
```

I obtain

```
AttributeDict({
    {
        'from': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        'to': '******************************************',
        'tokenId': ***
    },
    'event': 'Transfer',
    'logIndex': ***,
    'transactionIndex': **,
    'transactionHash': HexBytes('******************************************************************'),
    'address': '******************************************',
    'blockHash':    HexBytes('******************************************************************'),
    'blockNumber': 23504211
}
```

(I starred sensitive values) then using

```
print(w3.eth.block_number)
```

I get

```
23542487
```

So following the `current_block_number - tx_block_number` we find this tx has `23542487 - 23504211 = 38276` confrimations which seems like a crazy large number. Just to compare, at the same time https://polygonscan.com/ indicates `346` confirmations.

[image: screenshot of the polygon scan block explorer showing smaller number of confirmations]

I find this super confusing. Anyone could clarify how number of confirmations is computed on the Polygon Network?

EDIT:

Is it possible that `w3.eth.block_number` gives me the current ETH block number and not Polygon block number even if I connected to Polygon RPC node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that is a bit embarrasing, but it turns out I had a bug that was comparing wrong transaction hash, instead of previous one it was taking previous-previous one. Everything works fine, those numbers match, keep using Polygon!